# Multiline regex python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do some text file parsing where this pattern is repeated throughout the file:

```
VERSION.PROGRAM:program_name
VERSION.SUBPROGRAM:sub_program_name
```

My intent is to, given a progra_name, retrieve the sub_program_name for each block of text i mentioned above.

I have the following function that finds if the text actually exists, but doesn't print the sub_program_name:

```
def find_subprogram(program_name):
    regex_string = r'VERSION.PROGRAM:%s\nVERSION.SUBPROGRAM:.' % program_name
    with open('file.txt', r) as f:
    match = re.search(regex_string, f.read(), re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
         if match:
            print match.group()
```

I will appreciate some help or tips.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for multiple lines, then you don't want to use the MULTILINE modifier. What that does is it considers each line as its own separate entity to be matched against with a beginning and an end.

You also are not using valid regex matching techniques. You should look up how to properly use regex.

For matching any character, using `(.*)` not `%s`.

Here is an [example](http://regex101.com/r/jR6cP9/1)

Using `VERSION\.PROGRAM:YOURSTRING\nVERSION\.SUBPROGRAM:(.*)` will match the groups properly

```
re.compile('VERSION\.PROGRAM:%s\nVERSION\.SUBPROGRAM:(.*)'%(re.escape(yourstr)))
```

Comment: But I don't want match with any character, what I want is to match a block of text that contains the program name variable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3263140 could you provide an example?

Comment: Yes. For instance the file contains: VERSION.PROGRAM:PROGRAM_1
VERSION.SUBPROGRAM:sub_program_name VERSION.PROGRAM:PROGRAM_2
VERSION.SUBPROGRAM:sub_program_name ; What I want is only the sub_program_name of the PROGRAM_2, that is why I use the %s in the string. Using the string concatenation I get the same results, r'blabla' + program_name + r'blabla', but I choose the %s instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex has a typo, it's looking for `PRGRAM`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Unfortunately, it was only a copy paste fault.